# Displaying table data in python flask

Tags: html, html-table

I am listing down the data coming from the database in a table. But it is not aligning as a table.

what I want to display in the web page is,

```
Name       john mark 
Faculty    cs 
University xxx
```

But what I get in the web page is,

```
Name john mark 
Faculty cs 
University xxx
```

In my .html I have,

```
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
</tr>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help me with this as I am new to python flask.

Comment: Have you wrapped `tr` with table element?

Comment: No my .html only has what i have mentioned above.Do I have to wrapped it with a table element?

Comment: Yes, off course. You have to make a valid table structure. Then it will rendered correctly.

Comment: Yes it helped. Thank you @BhushanBabar

Comment: Hi, Kindly upvote and accept the answer if it really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is how valid table HTML should look.
You have not wrapped `tr` with `<table>` element.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So your code should look like this.

```
<table>
{% for item in data %}
<tr>
    <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
    <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think that there is any need for br tag  inside the table.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Yes, not needed but that does not break the table, I have tested, besides that was not the problem that caused problems to OP.

Comment: Agreed it doesnt cause any issue but it may cause issues in IE :) So we should avoid using anything that is not according to table markup.

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma Yes, I had noticed it , but it got copy pasted . Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```